# SQL Where clause Selecting Quantity

Tags: sql

I want to display the quantity of the product when particular product.

For example:

```
Name      Quantity
A           5
B           6
C           3
D           10
E           7
F           5
G           3
```

If I select A, in a picker, i want to display 5, and if I select E, I want to display 7....

It should be dynamic....

Can some one help me with a Query???

Answer (score 2):

Your query would be like this:

```
SELECT Quantity
FROM yourTable
WHERE Name = @Name
```

You would use a `WHERE` clause that included a parameter.  Then when querying you would pass in the value for the parameter and it would return the records that match.

Based on your comment your query would be:

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity) As orders 
FROM mobile_product 
WHERE product_name = '$product_name'
GROUP BY product_name
```

Comment: SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity) As orders FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name WHERE  product_name = '$product_name'...... Is this the right query????

Comment: @user1562991 what sql are you writing in?  the syntax can be different, MySql, SQL Server?

Comment: SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity) As orders FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name WHERE  product_name = '$product_name'...... Is this the right query????

Comment: @user1562991 see my edit, your `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` were reversed.  `GROUP BY` comes after the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Quantity from your_table where Name = '@name'
```

### edit

```
SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity) As orders 
FROM mobile_product
WHERE product_name = '$product_name'
GROUP BY product_name
```

Comment: SELECT product_name, SUM(product_quantity) As orders FROM mobile_product GROUP BY product_name WHERE  product_name = '$product_name'...... Is this the right query????

Comment: In PHP MyAdmin you have to replace `$product_name` with an actual product name.